# How to add words to Atom's spell checker dictionary?

Tags: atom-editor

Trying to get a bit more functionality out of Atom's spell checker and right now the false positives are making it less than useful.

How can I add a word to Atom's dictionary so it no longer shows up as misspelled?

Comment: As @voylinux pointed out it probably isn't implemented and can't be done without digging into system folders and adding words there manually.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This feature was released in version `1.12` of `Atom`, implemented in [Pull Request #120](https://github.com/atom/spell-check/pull/120).

To enable it, checkmark the option labeled `Add Known Words`, found in `Packages -> Settings View -> Open`, or shortcut `Cmd + ,`. Then go to `Packages` tab and search for `spell-check`.

Then, to add a word to the builtin dictionary, press `cmd-shift-:` while the cursor is on the misspelled word and select the item named *`Add to Known Words`*.

Comment: Do you know by chance how words can be removed again? I also tried to find the file to do it manually, but I cannot find it.

Comment: A restart isn't needed (tested with Atom 1.25 and spell-check 0.72.7)

Comment: In version 1.26.1, the path is `Packages -> Settings View -> Open`, or shortcut `Cmd + ,`. Then go to `Packages` tab and search for `spell-check`

Comment: You'll also probably need to go to Atom's settings for the spell-check package and check "Add Known Words" as explained in this Github Issue: https://github.com/atom/spell-check/issues/171#issuecomment-456234048

Comment: Packages -> Settings View -> Open ... search for spell-check ... tick "Add Known Words" checkbox ... then right click a misspelt word and click "Add to Known Words" in context menu ... no need for restart

Answer (score 6):

Looks like this feature does not exist yet in Atom.

[Link in project's Github](https://github.com/atom/spell-check/issues/10)

Answer (score 5):

Flávio Camilo's solution works for me.

I'm using Atom 1.15.0 on debian jessie (8.7) in xfce4 (4.10.1) 'ctrl+shift+:' opens the list of suggested corrections. The last entry 'Add to Known Words' appears when it is enabled on the plugin settings. In main menu 'Edit -> Preferences -> Packages' search for 'spell-check' (i'm seeing version 0.70.2) click on 'settings' search the checkbox on item 'Add Known Words', enable it and restart atom.

NOTE: I needed to do this twice, on the first restart the 'tick' on 'Add Known Words' was lost somehow.

Comment: Worked for me without a restart. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google brought me here and I guess it will happen to others as well, so:

There is an [issue](https://github.com/atom/spell-check/issues/10) about this open at the spell-check Github project. The last comment says adding words to dictionary will probably be there for Atom 1.11. I don't know what the ETA  is for that Atom version, but at the time I write the current stable release is 1.10.2, so I guess (sigh) soon.

Comment: Thank you for leaving this comment. Any sort of crumb trail will be helpful to posterity.