# How to add words to the Atom's linter-spell dictionary

Tags: atom-editor, spell-checking

I am using the *linter-spell* package instead of the "by default" *spell-check* in Atom.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228201/how-to-add-words-to-atoms-spell-checker-dictionary) somebody asks about adding words to the *spell-check* dictionary.

My question is how to add words to the *linter-spell* dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://atom.io/packages/linter-spell) for linter-spell:

> Misspellings can be corrected or added to personal dictionary using the [intentions](https://atom.io/packages/intentions) package via ctrl+enter on OSX and alt+enter on Linux and Windows.

Comment: And then, add to Latex dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Version `1.12` have this funcationality. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> while hover on word and select `add this word`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://atom.io/packages/linter-spell),

> Spell checking is done upon document save with misspellings displayed by linter. Misspellings can be corrected or added to personal dictionary using the intentions package via ctrl+enter on OSX and alt+enter on Linux and Windows.

A clear description of what you need to do is given [here](https://github.com/steelbrain/intentions/wiki/Intentions-API-:-List).

This works in such a way that it prompts you to `fix linter issue`, on clicking it you can assign a JS function to do whatever you want. I've also found that linter-spell relies on [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io/) and [GNU Aspel](http://aspell.net/) which means you can add the words to the system dictionary / or any dictionary in their path to make it work.

**Hunspell**

Add new word to hunspell dict.

`echo -e "*new_word\n#" | hunspell -a`

Hope this helps.